# Backbone: Collection not properly getting model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

Hi I am new to backbone and I have a page where I want to display information about a model. When I try to access it on the console it works out fine

Ex:

```
collection = new Poster.Colections.Posts()
collection.fetch({reset: true})
post = collection.get(1)
```

Above works fine

Now when I try to do it in a function on the `routers` page, it returns back undefined

**posts_router.js**

```
class Poster.Routers.Posts extends Backbone.Router
    routes:
        'posts':'index'
        '':'index'
        'posts/new': 'new'
        'posts/:id': 'show'

    initialize: ->
        @collection = new Poster.Collections.Posts()
        @collection.fetch({reset: true})


    index: ->
        view = new Poster.Views.PostsIndex(collection: @collection)
        $('#index_container').html(view.render().el)

    show: (id) ->
        post = @collection.get(id)
        view = new Poster.Views.PostsShow(model: post)
        $('#index_container').html(view.render().el)

    new: ->
        view = new Poster.Views.PostsNew(collection: @collection)
        $('#index_container').html(view.render().el)
```

I am really new to javascript and backbone and I am lost. Can someone please help

Comment: `fetch` is an AJAX call so you have to wait for the server to respond before the collection will have anything in it. You'd usually bootstrap the collection with some data in the page if you're expecting to use it right away.

Answer (score 0):

As mu already stated `fetch` is an asynchronous ajax call. So you have to wait for results and then do something. `backbone` gives you two options

**First option: Call `fetch` with callback object**

[`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) takes a callback object with `success` or `error`

```
collection = new Poster.Collections.Posts()
collection.fetch
  success: ->
    console.log 'Collection fetched'
    post = collection.get(1)
  error: ->
    console.error 'Unable to fetch collection'
```

**Second Option: Listen for changes on the collection**

When a model is added to a collection (which is done when fetching a collection) a `add` event is triggered

```
collection = new Poster.Collections.Posts.extend
  initialize: ->
    @on 'add', (model) =>
      console.log "model #{model} added"

collection.fetch()
```

[List of built-in events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog)